# Search depth of Alpha Go and Alpha Go Zero

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, monte-carlo, reinforcement-learning, artificial-intelligence

I cannot find reliable sources but someone says it is 40 moves and someone says it is 50+ moves. I read their papers and they use value function (NN) and policy function to trim the tree so more layers can be searched while spending less time searching less different positions.

My question is, is the search depth a fixed preset parameter? If so, approximately how much is it back to 2016 (Alpha Go) and 2018 (Alpha Go Zero)?

Comment: This question would fare better at the https://chess.stackexchange.com/  site.  You could flag and ask the mods to migrate!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen No worry I'll just do it by myself!